# Múltiplas conexões JDBC são "thread-safe"?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Estou criando um projeto bem simples em Java e PostgreSQL de `clientes` e `contatos` entre `clientes`.

Existe a tabela `clientes` com `id` e `nome`, e a tabela `contatos` com `id1` e `id2` que são referentes aos `clientes`.

O que acontece se em uma thread com uma conexão fizer um `select` contendo todos os contatos de um determinado cliente exatamente ao mesmo tempo que outra thread com outra conexão faz um `insert` ou `delete` ?

E ainda outro caso, se eu tiver um "procedimento salvo" que faça vários `selects` e `updates` diferentes e duas threads(conexões) executam este mesmo procedimento? Existe alguma garantia de ordem ?

Comment: De modo grosseiro, se a aplicação (fora do JDBC) não garantir a sincronia, fica a cargo do SGBD lidar com isso. O JDBC não tem inteligência dentro dele para lidar com diversas coisas. Acho que o máximo que ele contém é determinar que se abre uma transação, commitar seu resultado, dar _rollback_ e terminar a transação. Mas isso não é feito internamente, cabe a aplicação fazer essas chamadas. Quando tiver um tempo maior, e se ninguém tiver respondido satisfatoriamente, eu volto aqui, pesquiso e mando uma resposta